# Ignore foreign keys in mysql workbench model synchronization

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've made an ERD in MySQL Workbench, where I added foreign keys to visualize the relationships. In the actual database I want to work without the foreign keys (I'll organize that in my application).

When I export a create script, there is somewhere a function called "skip creation of foreign keys" or anything like that.

Now I want to sync the model directly with my database, but it looks like there is no equivalent option in the synchronization function.

I can also not find this option in the wizard for exporting an alter script, which would also be ok.

Am I just missing it or is that impossible?

Comment: Workbench is trying to protect you from the dangerous choice of having no FKs :)

Comment: I think there are pretty long discussions about the pros and cons. After reading for 2 hours and maybe 1/1000 of it I decided to go without. :D

Comment: Don't do it. Why don't you leave the FKs there? And still deal with them ("organize") in the application. It doesn't hurt, really to have everything double checked. Plus, you can sleep at night without fear of the database losing data integrity.

Comment: Maybe I add them later on, I don't know. Right now it would just get on my nerves because I have a lot of changes and the  fks are always crying.

Comment: For example I have MyISAM tables. I do not what to use innoDB. But I what to visualise relations in model so that other developers understand the DB structure. Then what?

Comment: "the fks are always crying" <-- You should pause for a second and consider that *the FK's are a symptom of a problem.  They are not the problem.* I agree with ypercube.  FK's are kind of like seat belts in your car.  You can often get away without using them, but they can save your life if anything goes wrong.

Comment: @Erik My question is over 2 years old. I'm now a fan of FKs and use them in all of my projects. I fully agree with both of you.